# Width: Auto not working for IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I am trying to use jQuery to resize a popup to fit its contents.

In Chrome and IE9, I use

```
$(windowSelector).css('width', 'auto');
```

and its all fine.

But the same line in IE8 causes the popup to stretch across the screen, width wise.

Does any one know any way to get around this?

Comment: Can you put an example in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following code though without giving some more details it might not do what you expect it to do (also doesn't work in IE7).

```
$(windowSelector).css('display', 'inline-block');
```

Answer (score 0):

`width:auto;` is the default width for all elements. The only context this makes sense is to reset a width set elsewhere. It doesn't set the width of the element to the width of the children.

IE is setting the with to 100% most likely because it doesn't have a parent element to constrain the width (default for block level elements). A width of auto applied to an inline element wouldn't do anything.

In order to size something to the width of it's children, you would need to get the height and width with JavaScript and set it on the parent element.